# Sonatype Nexus HA with Hazelcast in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, amazon-eks

does anybody know how to implement Nexus HA in a Kubernetes Cluster running in EKS?

I've installed Hazelcast with Helm and deployed Nexus with a Helm Chart too.

3 Pods are running but, when I'm looking into the container logs, I can't see the cluster formed by the 3 pods.

When I'm connecting to the DNS Nexus in a browser I got the error message: Application will be reloaded as the server has been restarted.

Comment: Could you clarify what you did (which charts & values)? AFAIK, clustering Nexus requires some shared storage (usually, s3 buckets backing your datastores), as well as a professional license - see https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/high-availability . not sure about hazelcast, might be another take on it ...

Comment: To further SYN's point, licensed instances are afforded support who should be able to help with this sort of question.